# how to select value in UI select value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

could you please tell me how to select value in UI-select value ?

Actually when user select any name I want to select **age** of item .Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/InxOyQRjrlrDJtx2VuzI?p=preview

```
<ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="multipleDemo" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in people | filter:$select.search">
      {{color.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Example

when I select **Amalie**  **multipleDemo** model value is **12** 
or if I select **Wladimir** is model value "30"..
it is multiple selected so model should be array ..

can we do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UI Changes** just add `on-select="OnClickSelect($item)"` and `on-remove="OnRemoveSelect($item)"` on `ui-select`

```
      <ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="multipleDemo" 
          on-select="OnClickSelect($item)" on-remove="OnRemoveSelect($item)"
          theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices  repeat="color in people | filter:$select.search">
          {{color.name}}
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
      <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo}}</p>
```

**Angular Changes** Add those functions inside `controller`

```
  $scope.OnClickSelect=function(item)   {
    $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age)
  }

 $scope.OnRemoveSelect = function(item) { 
   var index = $scope.multipleDemo.indexOf(item.age);
   $scope.multipleDemo.splice(index, 1);     
 }
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqzch1Mh9RJjbiYJPg4z?p=preview)

Comment: it is not current I need multiple select

Comment: it should give array of 'ages' ..not single age

Comment: As `ui-select` has `ng-model` you shouldn't be doing work manually. It not a good way to go.. I'd rather prefer to make it object like shown in below answer

Comment: @PankajParkar yes sure ... but your post does not providing answer to the Q .. can you please make it working ..

Comment: Have you checked my last comment of yesterday? It has plunkr covering what you want

Comment: @PankajParkar ... yes i checked it .. your answer is perfect and according to architecture ...

Answer (score 4):

The way `ui-select` has been designed, it needs `ng-model` value to `object`. Here you gave a primitive type

**Code**

```
$scope.model = {multipleDemo :[]};
```

**HTML**

```
<ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="model.multipleDemo" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color.age as color in people | filter:$select.search">
      {{color.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<p>Selected: {{test.multipleDemo}}</p>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCrEM4oC9iMSYZffbEAX?p=preview)

Comment: please share plunker

Comment: it is selecting whole object..http://plnkr.co/edit/InxOyQRjrlrDJtx2VuzI?p=preview .I need only `age` in object

Comment: it is not selecting array of age ..it is array of objects

Comment: @user944513 do little tweak in `repeat` like `repeat="color.age as color in people | filter:$select.search"` look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCrEM4oC9iMSYZffbEAX?p=info)